# FacebookSDK-5.0.25.0 for a Iframe Canvas App, after autherization user is redirected to canvas page

Tags: redirect, canvas, authorization, facebook-c#-sdk

I am working on web application with .net 3.5 using C# facebook SDK. Loading page inside Page Tab iframe with some information, and input button, on click of button i am doing auth.Authorize() with some permissions, FB Permission window opens fine, but once user click on allow button it is redirecting to application canvas page instead of Page tab.

Is there anything i am missing?

Regards
Imran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is to set auth.ReturnUrlPath which will bring user back to selected tab in facebook page. If your application is being added to multiple pages, then you can find out current pageid from "signed request" and set correct ReturnUrlPath, and attach ?sk=app_YOUR_APP_ID as querystring to ReturnUrlPath so current tab will be selected. your return path will look something similar to : http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=YOUR_PAGE_ID&sk=app_YOUR_APP_ID (make sure you handle both http and https)

This worked for me, hopefully will work for someone too.

-Ims

Answer (score 0):

Facebook C# SDK doesnt support tabs.

Only canvas apps are supported.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, is there any other alternative you will suggest? Everything is working good with C# SDK for my Iframe app (in company page tab), except when it asks for permission it just redirect to canvas page instead of tab. Trying to achive something similar to following link:
http://www.facebook.com/thinkdiff.net?ref=ts When you click on iAdvanced it asks for permissions and redirects back to iframe tab.

Comment: Make sure to set the ReturnUrlPath and it will redirect to the sepecified page rather than the canvas page.